# SQL Syntax to count unique users completing a task

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code which shows me what users has completed ticket and this lists each user and the date they close a ticket.  i.e.

```
Paul
Matt
Matt
Bob
Matt
Paul
Matt
Matt
```

At the moment I manually count each user myself to see their totals for the day.

**EDIT: Changed output as columns instead of rows:**

What I have been trying to do is get SQL Server to do this for me i.e. the final result to look like:

```
Paul  |  2
Matt  |  5
Bob   |  1
```

My code I am currently using is and I would be greatful if someone can help me change this so I can get it outputting something similar to above?

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime;

-- Date format: YYYY-MM-DD
SET @StartDate = '2013-11-06 00:00:00'
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()  -- Today


SELECT  (select Username from Membership where UserId =  Ticket.CompletedBy) as TicketStatusChangedBy

FROM         Ticket INNER JOIN
                      TicketStatus ON Ticket.TicketStatusID = TicketStatus.TicketStatusID INNER JOIN
                      Membership ON Ticket.CheckedInBy = Membership.UserId
WHERE TicketStatus.TicketStatusName = 'Completed' and Ticket.ClosedDate >= @StartDate --(GETDATE() - 1)
and Ticket.ClosedDate <= @EndDate --(GETDATE()-0)
ORDER BY Ticket.CompletedBy ASC, Ticket.ClosedDate ASC
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Google "sql server pivot queries".

Comment: Why do you need it in columns? Wouldn't the result in rows be sufficient? Then the query is simple.

Comment: I dont mind if its in rows or columns.  I am trying to avoid having to manually count each person stats (and I'm not clever enough to use pivot tables - this is something I got help with the last time this issue came up but was hoping there is something simple and not as complicated that I am missing!)

Comment: I am re-asking this question as pivot tables is too complicated for what I need

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you specifically want it in that format but if you had it in rows it's a lot simpler as a query:

```
SELECT Names, COUNT(Names)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Names
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9cf5/1)

Comment: this method sounds the best to me as simple but I cannot seem to count (select Username from Membership where UserId =  Ticket.CompletedBy) as Names).  Please excuse my lack of sql coding knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE  SomeTable 
(Name NVARCHAR(20))
GO

INSERT INTO SomeTable 
VALUES ('Mark'), ('Mark'),('Mark'),('SAM'),('SAM'),('Josh')
GO

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY Name
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE
        PIVOT (
                MAX(Total)
                FOR NAME 
                IN ([Mark], [SAM], [Josh])      
               )l
```

**Result Set**

```
Mark SAM  Josh
3    2    1
```

Obviously If there are many values in the table you will need to use Dynamic Sql, 1st build the Comma deliminited list of all the distinct values/names then pass the list of names in the 'IN' cluase of above query it to the Dynamic Sql.
 
**Using Dynamic SQL**

```
DECLARE @NameList NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @NameList =   @NameList + ',['  + Name + ']' 
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM SomeTable)t
SET @NameList =    STUFF(@NameList, 1, 1, '')
PRINT @NameList      --<---- for checking purpose to see if list is as expected

SET @Sql = ';WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY Name
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE
        PIVOT (
                MAX(Total)
                FOR NAME 
                IN ('+ @NameList + ')       
               )l'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

**Result Set**

```
Mark SAM  Josh
3    2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table(names varchar(100))

DECLARE @StartDate DateTime;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime;

-- Date format: YYYY-MM-DD
SET @StartDate = '2013-11-06 00:00:00'
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()  -- Today

insert into @t(names)
SELECT  (select Username from Membership where UserId =  Ticket.CompletedBy) as TicketStatusChangedBy

FROM         
Ticket INNER JOIN TicketStatus ON Ticket.TicketStatusID = TicketStatus.TicketStatusID INNER JOIN
         Membership ON Ticket.CheckedInBy = Membership.UserId
WHERE TicketStatus.TicketStatusName = 'Completed' and Ticket.ClosedDate >= @StartDate 
--(GETDATE() - 1)
and Ticket.ClosedDate <= @EndDate --(GETDATE()-0)
ORDER BY Ticket.CompletedBy ASC, Ticket.ClosedDate ASC

Select 
sum(case when names='Paul' then 1 else 0 end) as Paul,
sum(case when names='Matt' then 1 else 0 end) as Matt,
.
.
.
from @t
```